# How to solve laplace inverse using convolution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is find the laplace inverse of:
$Y(s) =\frac{18}{s(s-6)} + \frac{2}{s-6}$.

Are you able to solve this problem using convolution, by breaking the terms into:

$18 * \mathscr{L} (\frac{1}{s}) * \mathscr{L}(\frac{1}{s-6})$

I tried to solve it using this method, but did not get the same solution as solving through partial fractions.   Thanks in advance for the help!

The answer I found through partial fractions is: $5e^{6t}-3$

My solution is shown in the image below!

[image: Partial Fraction Laplace]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the same answer I found through partial fractions.  I have an extra $+2e^{6t}$ term!?

Comment: Show us your partial fractions decomposition.

Comment: @Yves I've added an image of my solution!

Comment: My apologies, I only posted a portion of the question which is what confused me when the answers did not match.  I've updated the question to reflect the original problem with the added $\frac{2}{s-6}$ term upon simplification.  If you have the time - it would be amazing if you could update your convolution solution to answer the full problem!  Thanks :)  (@Yves also)

Comment: There is now far enough material on this page for you to get/check the proper answer.

Comment: I know the correct answer, but I don't understand the convolution integral with respect to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [*Convolution*](http://www3.ul.ie/~mlc/support/Loughborough%20website/chap20/20_6.pdf) (see Part $2$) for the first part, we have:

$$18 \left( \mathscr{L}^{-1} \left(\dfrac{1}{s}\right) * \mathscr{L}^{-1} \left (\dfrac{1}{s-6}\right)\right) = 18(1 * e^{6t}) \implies \displaystyle 18 \int_0^t 1*e^{6 v}~dv = 3(-1 + e^{6t})$$

Using Inverse Laplace Transforms for the second part:

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1} \left(\dfrac{2}{s-6} \right) = 2 e^{6t}$$

Adding the two results:

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1} \left(Y(s) \right) = \mathscr{L}^{-1} \left(\frac{18}{s(s-6)} + \frac{2}{s-6}\right) = -3 + 5e^{6t}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{18}{s(s-6)} = \frac{A}{s} + \frac{B}{s-6} = \\ 
= \frac{A(s-6)+Bs}{s(s-6)} = \frac{s(A+B) - 6A}{s(s-6)}.$$

Then:

$$\frac{18}{s(s-6)} = \frac{s(A+B) - 6A}{s(s-6)},$$

which is satisfied when the numerators are equal. In particular, you need to pose:

$$\begin{cases}
A+B = 0\\
-6A = 18
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
B = 3\\
A = -3
\end{cases}.$$

Finally:

$$Y(s) = -\frac{3}{s} + \frac{3}{s-6}.$$

This can be easily anti-transformed:

$$y(t) = (-3 + 3 e^{6t})u(t).$$

Comment: Thank you for the partial fraction solution.  My question was however, how to solve the problem using normal fraction expansion and the convolution integral by separating the terms into $\frac{1}{s} \ \ and \ \ \frac{1}{s-s}$.